# Infuse Macros in Excel into BluePrism

Tags: blueprism

I have recently created a VBA Macro which allows the sorting of data based on columns. However, I am unsure of how to infuse this into the BluePrism or to modify the code into BluePrism as I am very new to BP. Any help will be appreciated.

Also apart from coding is there another approach which allows me to integrate the VBA macro code into BluePrism?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Excel VBA code directly in to Blue Prism. Code stages in Blue Prism will accept .NET languages: Visual Basic, C# and Visual J#.  In any case, you don't need to write your Macro into Blue Prism.  With the Excel sheet in question open and Blue Prism attached to the running instance of Excel, all you need to do is:

1) Select an Action stage.
2) select MS Excel VBO in the Business Object drop-down.
3) select the "Run Macro" in the Action drop down.

From inside this stage you can call the Macro by its given name.